# How to init a global variable exactly once, atomically and thread-safely

Tags: c, multithreading, assembly, thread-safety, atomic

I have created a global spinlock variable and a check variable:

```
pthread_spinlock_t locking;
int check = 1;
```

Now I want to init this variable exact one time:

```
if (check == 1)
  {
    // atomic part begins here
    pthread_spin_init(&locking, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    check = 0;
    // atomic part ends here
  }
```

So the two lines should happen in an atomic manner and I want to make this thing thread save.

Has anyone an idea how to deal with this?

I am not able to lock the whole if-statement with a mutex. Is it possible to make it atomic with assembly instructions?

Comment: you'll want to make that entire `if` block a critical section

Comment: as for your question, a mutex will work. This is a good pthreads tutorial, recommend reading it: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: is there another solition? Maybe with assembly instructions?

Comment: if you can't protect the whole `if` block (why not?) ,, you're going to have race conditions. 2 threads could get past `if (check == 1)`, only one of them will grab the mutex, the other will block. The one that grabbed the mutex will run `pthread_spin_init` then set `check` to 0,, but the blocking thread has already gotten past the `check == 1` check, and will run `pthread_spin_init` and `check = 0;` again when it wakes up.

Comment: All the C code compiles to assembly,, those regarding mutex attainment and related have to translate to a single assembly instruction, otherwise thread safety wouldn't be guaranteed. I don't know what those assembly instructions are, and from a C perspective, don't care. You're writing C, so you shouldn't either.

Comment: @yano I m fully aware of this situation! The things you told me I know already. But the question was if  it is possible to make it atomic with assembly instructions?

Comment: Anything that can be done with C can be done with assembly instructions, but if you are asking _what_ assembly instructions, then the answer will have to take into account the target architecture and maybe the target operating system. One way to answer the question would be to write the "C" code, and then single-step through it at the assembly level in a debugger.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Recommend rephrasing your question or deleting this question and asking a new one. You say you're asking about assembly, but C is front and center in the title, tags, and question body, and you literally don't mention assembly until the last sentence of your question, after an edit no less. If it's assembly you want, replace the C tag with the Assembly tag and add your architecture. Better yet, write the C code you want, then look at the generated assembly. Some misunderstanding about that would be a better question to ask.

Comment: @yano: why not? Because that would be ridiculously inefficient.  All you need is a read-only access of `check` to see if it's definitely already non-zero, and only *then* take a lock and sort out the details of exactly one thread running some init code.  e.g. have them all do an atomic `compare_exchange_strong`.  I think you might have to use `_Atomic int check`, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm intrigued but not sure I follow, please answer the question. What's ridiculously inefficient.. the other threads blocked right before `if (check == 1)`?

Comment: @yano: no, simply that taking a mutex at all requires an atomic RMW operation so all threads would contend for modifying the lock object itself.  You can do *much* better than that with an `atomic_int` that threads normally *only* read so it can stay hot in every core's private L1d cache, just as cheap as a plain global with no locking.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh ok. Thanks, wasn't aware that contending for a mutex was so much worse than an atomic, but makes sense now if an atomic check is simply a read. I thought you meant there was something wrong with the logic of my critical section suggestion. Really I wouldn't want different threads contending for a one-time initialization anyway,, would want to put that in a single-threaded path before launching the workers if at all possible.

Comment: @yano yeah I have no idea what the OP's use-case is.  Usually you can avoid this, or it's not a problem if multiple threads do `check = 0` with atomic.  If it's something like a singleton, my answer uses `check` pretty much the same way that compilers implement a guard variable to make sure only 1 thread runs the initializer for `static T bar = some_constructor();`.  (Except the threads that lose the race wait for the thread doing the init so they can actually use a fully-initialized `bar`.)  But anyway, the fast path is still one read-only compare/branch.

Comment: Why won't a mutex cut it?  Every alternative would boil down to building a mutex by hand as the variable is too large to be updated atomically.

Comment: @fuz How would you do it w/ a mutex, exactly?

Comment: @curiousguy Put a mutex around the sequence where you check `check`.  Though this seems a bit redundant when you try to initialise a spin lock anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So other threads can be running `if(check == 1)` while you're potentially modifying `check`?  There's no way to make this strictly safe with a lock inside the `if`, because you have a read access *outside* the critical section.  That would be data-race UB.

If the `if(check==1)` part is supposed to run all the time and almost always find it false, you want to make that check very cheap and scalable to multiple parallel readers.  Protecting that access with a lock would not be efficient; all readers would have to modify the lock itself.

C11 introduces `<stdatomic.h>` that gives you portable access to atomic loads, stores, and RMWs.  You can make `check` into an `atomic_int`.

Then read-only access to it can be about as cheap as a plain global with no locking.  It can stay hot in every core's private L1d cache if it's read frequently and doesn't get written.

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

atomic_int check = 1;

void foo() {
    int old = 1;
    if (atomic_load_explicit(&check, memory_order_relaxed) == old) {
        bool success = atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&check, &old, 0);
        if (success) {
            // this thread did the exchange
        }
        // else some other thread saw check=1 and beat us to the punch
        // and old is updated to the previous value of check
    }
}
```

Compiles on the [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxLgHZSAB1QLC62nsMTQS8fNTorG3sjJxdOdyUVMNoGAmZiAgDjU05FZUxVPxS0ggi7R2c3RVT0zKCchWqS6zLoiriASkVUA2JkDgByKQBma2RDLABqcSGdBvRmIiM8ZAA6BGnscQAGAEFh0fHMKZm5h1R9NY3tvd3rhdQl5AB9awIJ5AR8gGtjgBEJzjTWS3XYAN1QeHQExoqAg7SmrmBOwmKImrwm%2Bih03%2BgKGSNRaKoEwg90eT1YqGY6CemAAHh5WMtCBApAA2D7fUgTIyYIwkACeTxIWGIT2IymYtMw6Hh2OxGNYMoR%2BIJqLO%2BgmCgMyD6CgUfwmpOWTzQRg8aUwNNpHxEwEtDWIdGALMk7M%2ByC%2BXLZmK5W3aQOuqtReCJEC1OswetliMDQdVAHp4xMCAg8PqU%2BKqRN8FCU0c6TbRJhY0HxK5fiWE0nlEpNQ8jqg88RkwhM1CFMwAO7vd1fbGcQ3aCZOBYTAzp1Ato4eAy0D6VssV27l679TqsED9ACs/VIpn6W13qE3OjkcjrPT6U0kQ04u4Im8P7U6XxAQ24K1ZPC3PCGki3rJDAAHNwACcrJCJu3C7kYXBbFse6Pkem67goIAIQ%2BB5rqQcCwEgpoeHg7BkBQEAEURFTAKBkikFQREEM4aEQA4SGkA41hpPym53qQpo8vQADytCsFxWGkFgRi2uwrH4OKBSgpGrF0vkBgMdxu6vMorGMg4xCcXoWDqaQBDEHgsH9HenQ0PQTBsBwPD8IIwiiCgZ4yEIeAOGhkCdKgHhJGh/QALTWhMQUCUMYUAOpsKwqF5AUGgQOYtTZKQ5ilFEMTBN4vh0KlOWhH4mXlLEuSJIUjQFfUCVJEU6Qla0ZUNMU1VVMUjXZZwnQKN0vT2eum47ohYnHv0tJAayQWstwEzADqEygSskjErghAkNet5cnoZoUc2wzdRMp4yHI95Ic%2BpCvn%2BKxbFukicHd76cFskhAZwQGQf00GkLBz0Ifuh6kGNqHocZ504TAiAoA8hHEeQlDkcRIBpEYM3AEBkgIXRrAMcQTEsWJ7G0JxRl8VoBBCSJMm8lJAyA7J%2BRqApgWA8pyCqQMPGaRuYk6XpxD8gZnP3qZ5mWbRdCMCw0kOQIOTOWIbnyDp3lwkD/l%2BIFIXIGFEXRbF8UVUlKX6FkZjaJ1bSeLlSRtSEeW0JbzW1ZVrWm3U5WM67DXNFlVstTU7tpQHTSRKVXA9X1fQR59w0A8h/Q7AASgAsjNc0LUBy2rfgRD7TeORHTDe2bYdx2yDIZ1YRdV1DCsQwN43TdN5933x0DKGKKDmFPoN/SSLu7fA2D1edApeN%2BCA3BAA%3D) compiler explorer to efficient asm for the `check != 1` fast path:

```
# gcc9.2 -O3 for x86-64
foo:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR check[rip]     # plain asm load, atomic because it's aligned
        cmp     eax, 1
        je      .L4
        ret
.L4:
        xor     edx, edx
        lock cmpxchg    DWORD PTR check[rip], edx
        ret
check:
        .long   1
```

And similarly cheap asm even on weakly-ordered ISAs like AArch64.

Reads of `atomic_int` can't be optimized away or hoisted out of loops.

`int tmp = check;` is like `atomic_load_explicit` with the default `memory_order_seq_cst`.  On x86 this doesn't cost any extra in asm, but on other ISAs it requires barriers for load ordering.  I used `relaxed`; if you want it to mean that it's safe to read some other data you should use `acquire` or the default seq_cst.

---